# Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed. Electron Builder

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, electron-builder

I can't build electron app using squirrel. Though iconUrl is valid.
package.json:

```
"squirrelWindows": {
  "iconUrl": "http://95.85.39.111:5005/skylog.ico"
},
```

Error:

> Unhandled exception: System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed.

Full trace:

```
Error: Exit code: 4294967295. Command failed: 
C:\Users\emretekince\AppData\Local\electron-
builder\cache\Squirrel.Windows\Squirrel.Windows-1.6.0.0\Update.com --
releasify C:\Users\emretekince\Desktop\DCSLogBook\client\dist\win\skylog-
0.1.0-full.nupkg --releaseDir C:
\Users\emretekince\Desktop\DCSLogBook\client\dist\win
2017-07-11 14:17:28> Unhandled exception: System.UriFormatException: Invalid 
URI: The hostname could not be parsed.
at System.Uri.CreateThis(String uri, Boolean dontEscape, UriKind uriKind)
at System.Uri..ctor(String uriString)
at NuGet.ManifestMetadata.NuGet.IPackageMetadata.get_ProjectUrl()
at NuGet.LocalPackage.ReadManifest(Stream manifestStream)
at NuGet.ZipPackage.EnsureManifest()
at NuGet.ZipPackage..ctor(String filePath, Boolean enableCaching)
at Squirrel.Update.Program.ReleasifyElectron(String package, String targetDir, String baseUrl)
at Squirrel.Update.Program.executeCommandLine(String[] args)
at Squirrel.Update.Program.main(String[] args)


⚠️  Cannot delete temporary dir "C:\Users\EMRETE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\electron-builder-jyFHH6": Error: ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir 'C:\Users\EMRETE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\electron-builder-jyFHH6'
    at Object.fs.rmdirSync (fs.js:851:18)
    at rmkidsSync (C:\Users\emretekince\Desktop\DCSLogBook\client\node_modules\fs-extra\lib\remove\rimraf.js:292:11)
    at rmdirSync (C:\Users\emretekince\Desktop\DCSLogBook\client\node_modules\fs-extra\lib\remove\rimraf.js:281:7)
    at rimrafSync (C:\Users\emretekince\Desktop\DCSLogBook\client\node_modules\fs-extra\lib\remove\rimraf.js:252:7)
    at process.cleanup (C:\Users\emretekince\Desktop\DCSLogBook\client\node_modules\electron-builder-util\src\tmp.ts:36:13)
    at emitOne (events.js:120:20)
    at process.emit (events.js:210:7)
    at process.emit (C:\Users\emretekince\Desktop\DCSLogBook\client\node_modules\source-map-support\source-map-support.js:430:21)
    at process.exit (internal/process.js:154:15)
    at printErrorAndExit (C:\Users\emretekince\Desktop\DCSLogBook\client\node_modules\electron-builder-util\src\promise.ts:5:11)
    at tryCatcher (C:\Users\emretekince\Desktop\DCSLogBook\client\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (C:\Users\emretekince\Desktop\DCSLogBook\client\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:512:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (C:\Users\emretekince\Desktop\DCSLogBook\client\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:569:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (C:\Users\emretekince\Desktop\DCSLogBook\client\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:614:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (C:\Users\emretekince\Desktop\DCSLogBook\client\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:689:18)
    at Async._drainQueue (C:\Users\emretekince\Desktop\DCSLogBook\client\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:133:16)
    at Async._drainQueues (C:\Users\emretekince\Desktop\DCSLogBook\client\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:143:10)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (C:\Users\emretekince\Desktop\DCSLogBook\client\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:17:14)
```

Comment: Can you add the full stacktrace?

Comment: @mr.freeze added.

Answer (score 0):

That is a valid URL, but it looks like the internal logic that handles these is having trouble parsing the hostname out of it (since there is none, you've replaced hostname with an IP). A solution might be to raise an issue for https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows

A better solution might be to migrate away from Squirrel and use the NSIS installer that comes with electron-builder. Iirc the primary maintainer, develar, advocates the usage of NSIS over Squirrel. And from my experience it is much cleaner and easy to use. The only reason to use Squirrel in my opinion would be if you need to integrate with another tool that relies on squirrel.